# How can I fix a problem with runing conda django virtual enviroment?

Tags: python, django

Can anyone help me with following problem? I encountered that during one of the courses I am taking.

### I use ios Catalina 10.15 therefor I use zhs as bash is no longer supported by mac

I am trying to  run virtual server so I can see my webpage

I managed to run the virtual server once only (python manage.py runserver) and after the restart I have problem with it eversince.

```
> first_proj python manage.py runserver

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "manage.py", line 10, in main

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>

    main()

  File "manage.py", line 16, in main

    ) from exc

ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

when I check for django (django-admin --version), turns out it is installed, I am getting this ouput:

2.2.5 (version of Django installed).

my django directory is:  /Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/envs/projectname/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django

maybe it is something about the directory django is installed (?)

thanks for any help.

Comment: If project is running with virtual environment, then you should activate it first.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I recommend you to install Anaconda in /opt/anaconda3, not in /somepath/opt/anaconda3. And when you install it, accept the auto-init.

Second, Zsh and Anaconda must be configured separately so they can work together. Add Anaconda to your paths (/etc/paths). You can check to see if everything is going well by applying any conda command:

```
$ conda info -e
```

Third, remember to activate your environment before applying runserver.

```
$ source activate <conda-env-name>
```

Using this command, you can see all the libraries installed in your environment: (and check if django is there)

```
(<conda-env-name>) username@mac: ~ $ conda list -e
```

And then make runserver:

```
(<conda-env-name>) username@mac: ~ $ python3 manage.py runserver
```